# XCode TAB bar application with main menu screen

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, development-environment, tabbar

I am trying to create a basic tab bar application, with 4 tabs, without using the 'storyboard' feature, My problem is that when the app lunches, It desplays the first tab as my first view, but I want to display a custom xib like my 'main menu' with 4 unselected tabs, and only when I press on one of the tabs, the specific choosen page/nib will open, is there a way to do it?

p.s. I didnt post any code because I am talking about the most basic implementation of xcode's tabed bar application

Picture of what I am trying to accomplish is attached.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2s15hme&s=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this will be acceptable to Apple, since a tab bar controller should always show a selected tab -- it might violate the HIG. I think it would be better to display a modal view controller at startup for your menu screen, which wouldn't show tabs, but could have buttons (corresponding to the tabs) to take you directly to one of the tabs when the modal controller is dismissed. If you present this controller from the viewDidAppear method of the controller in the first tab (with no animation), it will be the first thing the user sees.

Comment: Sounds good, could you share a piece of code to help out alittle more?

Comment: @AlexFleshler  I think you will learn best if you try it yourself first, and come back with specific questions if you get stuck. To get started, create a view controller in a xib or storyboard with buttons that correspond to each tab, and any helpful text you want to present to the user. Present it modally from the viewDidAppear method of the controller in the first tab. In the Buttons' action methods, you can use self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1 for instance to select the second tab, then dismiss the modal controller. That's all you should need to do.